# Error: Cannot read field "color" because "u" is null RED BLACK TREE

Tags: dictionary, null, red-black-tree, insertion, red-black-tree-insertion

Hello I have an assignment to implement a RBT tree and then as an application insert dictionary in it for more efficient insertion and searching operations.
When I insert the dictionary file it only reads the first word and 2nd word but doesn't fix up the insertion of the 2nd word and this error shows up [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvzd0.png) when I debugged the problem is in the insertfixup method. I think that's where the u is but I'm not sure why even if I don't initialize u with anything it gives me the same error so I tried to initialize it with TNULL and it still the same I hope my problem is clear

```
private void insertFixUp(Node x) {
Node u = TNULL;
    while (x.parent.color == 1){
        if(x.parent == x.parent.parent.right){
            u=x.parent.parent.left;
        if (u.color == 1){
            u.color =0;
            x.parent.color = 0;
            x.parent.parent.color = 1;
            x = x.parent.parent;
        }
        else {
            if(x == x.parent.left) {
            x = x.parent;
            rightRotate(x);
        }
            x.parent.color=0;
            x.parent.parent.color=1;
            leftRotate(x.parent.parent);
        }
    } else {
            u = x.parent.parent.right;

            if (u.color == 1){
                u.color =0;
                x.parent.color = 0;
                x.parent.parent.color = 1;
                x = x.parent.parent;
            }
            else {
                if(x == x.parent.right) {
                    x = x.parent;
                    leftRotate(x);
                }
                x.parent.color=0;
                x.parent.parent.color=1;
                leftRotate(x.parent.parent);
            }
        }
        if(x == root){
            break;
        }
  }
    root.color=0;

}
```